# How to format data in C# ASP.Net MVC for datatable.net ajax call

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I was wondering how I can pass data to datatable.net in an asp.net mvc 4 application.

like this example:
http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/ajax.html

The output format I want is like this, but I can't figure out how to produce this result:

```
{
"aaData": [
[
  "Trident",
  "Internet Explorer 4.0",
  "Win 95+",
  "4",
  "X"
],
[
  "Trident",
  "Internet Explorer 5.0",
  "Win 95+",
  "5",
  "C"
]
]
}
```

So far I have something like this:

```
 public JsonResult GetDataList(int? assetId)
    {
        var tableData = DBData.ToList();

        var res = new JsonResult
        {
            JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
            Data = ??? // I must do something here with tableData
        };


        return res;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, my problem was I had to use an array of object (object[]), not a list

```
 public JsonResult GetData(int? Id)
    {
        List<sp_data_R_Result> tableData;
        if (assetId != null)
            tableData = DBData.Where(x => x.Id== Id).ToList();
        else
            tableData = DBData.ToList();

        var res = new JsonResult
        {
            JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
            Data = new
                    {
                        aaData = from d in tableData
                                 select new object[]
                                {
                                  d.col1,
                                  d.col2,
                                  ...
                                 }
                    }
        };

        return res;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to convert the datatable into json?? Please correct me if I m wrong. You can do it using json.net library:

http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(table, Formatting.Indented);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below JsonResult, it should return the result in the format the datatables plugin is expecting.

```
public JsonResult GetDataList(int? assetId)
{
    var tableData = DBData.ToList();

    return Json(new {
        aaData = ???
    },
    "application/json", Encoding.UTF8, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

This should return your Json as below:

```
{
    "aaData": [
        {
          "Trident",
          "Internet Explorer 4.0",
          "Win 95+",
          "4",
          "X"
        },
        {
          "Trident",
          "Internet Explorer 5.0",
          "Win 95+",
          "5",
          "C"
        },
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this one worked:

```
return Json(new {
                    aaData = Json(list).Data
                },
                "application/json", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```